# Can a self-inverse function y=f(x) always be written as an equation that is symmetric with respect to x and y?

Tags: functions, inverse

For example, y=x/(x-1) is easily shown to be self-inverse, since f(f(x)) = x. For another approach, cross-multiply and rearrange terms to get xy = x+y.  Since the expression is symmetric with respect to x and y, it must be self-inverse, since an equation that gives y in terms of x will also give x in terms of y.  Is it always possible, at least in theory, to use this second approach to show that a function is self-inverse?

Comment: A function $f$ for which $y=f(x)$ always satisfies a given equation symmetric in $x$ and $y$ is not necessarily self-inverse. $x^2 y^2 + xy = x^3+y^3$ has solutions $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is positive, sort of. If you already know that $y=f(x)$ is a self-inverse function, i.e. $y=f(x)\iff x=f(y)$, then $y=f(x)$ is also equivalent to $(y-f(x))(x-f(y))=0$, which is symmetrical in $x$ and $y$.

For example, your example is equivalent to:

$$\left(y-\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\left(x-\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=0$$

However, the onus would be on you to prove that the new equation, symmetrical in $x$ and $y$, is indeed equivalent to the original equation $y=f(x)$. (Of course, without using the fact that $f$ is self-inverse, otherwise you would have a circular argument.) This is because, as per @aschepler's comment, some functions that are not self-inverse will (via the above construction) give an equation which would produce a plot that is symmetrical in $x$ and $y$, but would not be equivalent to the original equation $y=f(x)$.

Comment: I see that an expression symmetric in x and y is not necessarily a function. If it is in fact a function y=f(x) (which may not be all that easy to show), would it then follow that the function is self-inverse?  For every point (a,b) on the curve, there is a point (b,a).  Isn't that enough to show that it is self-inverse?

Comment: Another way of saying pretty much the same thing is to say that an equation symmetric in x and y may consist of several pairs of functions y=f(x) along with x=f(y), as in the case of y=x^2 and x=y^2.  These curves are reflections of one another in the line y=x.  If there is just one curve y=f(x), it coincides with x=f(y) and is therefore self-inverse.

Comment: I have been thinking about your follow-up question: I think it a matter of *domain*. Had you, say, restricted the domain of your function to $[2,+\infty)$, which makes it not self-inverse, then the construction above (if a function) provides an extension of your function, which *is* self-inverse, but is *not* your original function. So, I think the resulting function (if a function) is always an extension of your original function, to a bigger domain, and is self-inverse, so, for example, a sufficient condition would be that its *domain is no bigger than the domain of the original function*.

Comment: So, the bottom line is, maybe: the sufficient condition that $y=f(x)$ is self-inverse is that (a) The relation $(y-f(x))(x-f(y))=0$ is a function, and (b) The domain of that function is no bigger than the domain of the original function. In your case, the domain is $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$. There may be other sufficient condition.